# How to retain Select value after ajax within a partial view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In my ASP.NET Core web application I have a partial view that will need to be placed in several views and be able to respond to dynamic data that will vary based on the view that's rendering this partial at the time.  The red box in the image blow represents the area the partial is rendered.

[image]

The partial is essentially a `Select` that will call a Stored Procedure and return a datatable and render out the table to the partial view.  I am able to select an option on the page and have it call the SP and see all relevant data from the datatable and can write that out on the page no problem.  The problem I am having is that every time the partial refreshes via ajax, the `Select` returns to the default "Select" value and does not keep the previously selected option selected.

For the sake of brevity, assume that the `FeedbackQueries` object just contains 4 string elements.

**_FeedbackQueryResultPartial.cshtml**

```
@using Contract.Shared;
@model FeedbackQueries


<style>
#select {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>

<div id="feedbackQueryResultPartial">
    <div style="height:25px;">
        <div id="select">
            <select name="StoredProcs" id="StoredProcs" onchange="selectQuery()">
                <option value="Select">Select</option>
                @foreach (FeedbackQuery query in Model.Queries)
                {
                    @Html.Raw($"<option value='{query.SprocName}'>{query.SprocName}</option>");
                }
            </select>
        </div>

        <div id="feedbackQueryDiv" class="row">
            @if (Model.FeedbackQueryResults.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                <h3>DataTable goes here</h3>
            }
            else
            {
                <h3>No rows were returned from your query. Please select another.</h3>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Processing.cshtml**

```
@using Contract.Parent
@using Contract.Shared
@model Processing
<script>
        function showFeedbackPartial(x, y, z, q) {
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                url: '@Url.Action("GetFeedbackQueryDatatable", "Client")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { databaseConnectionString: x, storedProcedure: y, page: z, Model: q },
                success: function (result) {
                    var selected = $('#StoredProcs').val();
                    console.log(selected);
                    if (result.rowCount > 0) {
                        console.log(result.rowCount);
                        var databaseConnectionString = x;
                        var storedProcedure = y;
                        var page = z;
                        var model = q;
                        var url = '@Url.Action("ViewFeedbackQueryPartial", "Client")';
                        $("#feedbackQueryResultPartial").load(url, { databaseConnectionString, storedProcedure, page, model });
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById('feedbackQueryDiv').innerHTML = '<h3>No rows were returned from your query.  Please select another.</h3>';
                    }
                    $('#StoredProcs').val(selected);
                    $("#StoredProcs option[value='Select']").remove();
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        function selectQuery() {
            var e = document.getElementById('StoredProcs');
            var ev = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
            var p = 'Processing';
            var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.FeedbackQueries));
            console.log(model);
            showFeedbackPartial('@Model.Client.DatabaseConnectionString', ev, p, model);

        }
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            document.getElementById('feedbackQueryDiv').innerHTML = '<h3>Select a query to view feedback.</h3>';
        });
    </script>
}
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
    <partial name="_FeedbackQueryResultPartial" for="@Model.FeedbackQueries" />
...
</form>
```

**Controller actions that render the Processing view**

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Processing(int Id)
        {
            ViewBag.Id = Id;
            Processing processing = new Processing();

            //Get pertinent information for Client 
            processing.Client = _clientProcessingService.GetSingleClient(Id, _appSettings.MOPConfigConnectionString);
            processing.Client.DatabaseConnectionString = _clientProcessingService.GetClientConnectionFromConfig(processing.Client, _appSettings);
            processing.Steps = _clientProcessingService.GetClientSteps(processing.Client.DatabaseConnectionString, "Processing");
            processing.CurrMoInfo.CurrMo = _clientProcessingService.GetProcessingCurrMo(processing.Client.DatabaseConnectionString);
            processing.FeedbackQueries = _clientProcessingService.GetFeedbackQueriesFromDb(processing.Client.DatabaseConnectionString, "Processing");

            return View(processing);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Processing(Processing Model)
        {
            //Get pertinent information for Client 
            Model.Client = _clientProcessingService.GetSingleClient(Model.Client.ClientID, _appSettings.MOPConfigConnectionString);
            Model.Client.DatabaseConnectionString = _clientProcessingService.GetClientConnectionFromConfig(Model.Client, _appSettings);
            Model.Steps = _clientProcessingService.GetClientSteps(Model.Client.DatabaseConnectionString, "Processing");
            Model.CurrMoInfo.CurrMo = _clientProcessingService.GetProcessingCurrMo(Model.Client.DatabaseConnectionString);
            Model.FeedbackQueries = _clientProcessingService.GetFeedbackQueriesFromDb(Model.Client.DatabaseConnectionString, "Processing");

            return View(Model);
        }
```

**Controller action that renders the partial**

```
public IActionResult ViewFeedbackQueryPartial(string DatabaseConnectionString, string StoredProcedure, string Page, FeedbackQueries Model)
{
    if(StoredProcedure == "Select")
    {
        return PartialView("_FeedbackQueryResultPartial", Model);
    }
    Model.FeedbackQueryResults = _clientProcessingService.GetFeedbackQueryDataTable(DatabaseConnectionString, Page, StoredProcedure);

    return PartialView("_FeedbackQueryResultPartial", Model);
}
```

I have tried so many different ways of maintaining this value.  Adding it to the model, adding it to the Viewbag and countless other methods of attempting to retain this value somewhere and regardless of success or failure, keep the value and change it to the selected option via javascript.  It resets to "Select" every time the partial is reloaded after the ajax call is made.

This also presents another problem wherein, when I submit the form on the `Processing` view by clicking `RUN` the page will refresh and go to the next step in the process but ideally what should also happen is that the value in the partial is kept, the query is ran again and the user doesn't need to select a new value at any point unless they want to run a different SP to see different data in the table.

Is this even possible or am I trying to do this the entirely wrong way?

Comment: The extremely annoying thing is that by all accounts this should be working.  I excluded several log statements from this post to cut down on comments and keep the code relevant but when I F12 in Chrome to see what's going on, all of what I expect to see, I do.  the `OnChange` is correctly logging the selected option, the `InnerHTML` is being changed appropriately as expected, but this select is just throwing me for a loop here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your issue, you may need to pass the selected `SprocName` from Parent View to partial view with `Model`.

1. Add `SelectedSprocName` to `FeedbackQueries`

   ```
   public class FeedbackQueries
   {
       public string SelectedSprocName { get; set; }
       public List<FeedbackQuery> Queries { get; set; }
       public FeedbackQueryResults FeedbackQueryResults { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Change View to set `SelectedSprocName`

   ```
   function showFeedbackPartial(x, y, z, q) {
       $.ajax({
           cache: false,
           url: '@Url.Action("GetFeedbackQueryDatatable", "Process")',
           type: 'POST',
           success: function (result) {
               var selected = $('#StoredProcs').val();                   
               model.SelectedSprocName = selected;
               var url = '@Url.Action("ViewFeedbackQueryPartial", "Process")';
               $("#feedbackQueryResultPartial").load(url,{ databaseConnectionString, storedProcedure, page, model });
               console.log('after load' + selected);
              // your rest code
           }
       });
   }
   ```
3. Partial View set selected option

   ```
   @foreach (FeedbackQuery query in Model.Queries)
   {
       if (query.SprocName == Model.SelectedSprocName)
       {
           @Html.Raw($"<option value='{query.SprocName}' selected='true'>{query.SprocName}</option>");
       }
       else
       {
           @Html.Raw($"<option value='{query.SprocName}'>{query.SprocName}</option>");
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was so close to figuring this out all I was missing was that if statement. Just to make a quick point about your answer, due to the Processing view and the Partial having separate models, I had to assign the value on the partials model (`FeedbackQueries`) from within the controller action that's called in the ajax function. Once I got that assigned though, your condition check in the partial view worked like a charm and retained the value on post back.